# cache in WCF (SOAP) with basicHttpsBinding - simple example

Tags: wcf, caching, soap

I created simple WCF service to return list of data to client. 
To improve the performance in WCF, I need to add Cache to hold some reference values.  This way I do not have to hit database every time.
This is my first time writing cache.  So below is the list of question.

- Any simple sample example I can refer
- where do I need to initialize this cache object

  1. Do I need to create operationContract and service method for caching? 
        If this is case, how can I initialize this process in Service
  2. Do I need to write class to hold this initializing logic?  Do I need to write if logic to make sure  this got populated in beginning of any method?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a AspNetCacheProfile attribute above the method which you want to cache. This ensures that the particular method is not invoked every time the client requests data from the method. The Cache Profile must be first defined in the web.config file.

```
[ServiceContract] AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class MyService
{ 
    [AspNetCacheProfile("MyCacheProfile")]
    public SomeData GetData(int id)
    {
         // ...
    }
}
```

And in the web.config file configure the profile MyCacheProfile as :

```
<system.web>
   <caching>
      <outputCacheSettings>
         <outputCacheProfiles>
            <add name="MyCacheProfile" duration="30"
varyByParam="none" sqlDependency="MyTestDatabase:MyTable"/>
         </outputCacheProfiles>
      </outputCacheSettings>
   </caching>
</system.web>
```

The attribute "cacheDuration" sets the amount of time a response should be cached in seconds and  "varyByParam" allows you to specify a query string parameter that is used to cache response.

For more detailed information refer [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230443(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: I believe the above example applies to Restful service with WebHttpBinding.   Mine is SOAP with basicHttpBinding.   Do you think it is working for SOAP?  Thanks